# How much food when taking vitamin supplements?

Tags: absorption-absorb, multi-vitamin

If you want to take a few vitamin supplements but don't have time for a meal, would 50 calories or so of food be good enough?

What is the minimum amount of food intake that would be necessary for good absorption of the vitamins?

(Why can't I take vitamins with meals? I have an unpredictable work schedule and do not carry my bottles of vitamin with me, and it's just more convenient for me this way.)

Comment: I've edited your question to make it less personal. If you disagree, you can choose to roll it back, but it may then be closed for asking for personal medical advice.

Comment: The question is not about an empty stomach vs with a meal. The question is "how much" food is necessary​.

Comment: @JohnP I've edited the question. Is it better now?

Comment: Yes, much better. I've retracted my downvote and close vote and even upvoted it.

Comment: @CareyGregory tx!

Comment: What prevents you to take vitamins with a meal?

Comment: @Jan I have an unpredictable work schedule and do not carry my bottles of vitamin with me, and it's just more convenient for me this way.